# Jquery inserting a variable into json function

Tags: javascript, var

Everything works in the code below but I would like to take "filterItemID[0].Zone1", remove "Zone1" and insert the var getPriceID.  I've tried doing this multiple ways but nothing seems to work.

```
function jsonParser(json) {
  $.getJSON('../../data/empdata.json', function(data) {
    var filterItemID = $.grep(data, function(element, index) {
      return element.ItemId == findItemID;
    });
    var getPriceID = $("#PriceIDs").val();

    var UpdateCostField = filterItemID[0].Zone1;
    $(contentpaneIFParent).find("#Cost").append().val(UpdateCostField);
    $(contentpaneIF).css('background-color', 'transparent');

  });

}
```

Comment: You're trying to use `filterItemID` before the AJAX callback function executes.

Comment: Returning something from the callback function is useless, nothing uses it.

Comment: Now that I've cleaned up the indentation, I see that I was wrong. It's in the right scope.

Comment: Show a sample of the JSON, and what you're trying to do with it. It's not clear what you mean by remove `Zone1` and insert `getPriceID`.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, but I think what you want is this: `var UpdateCostField = filterItemID[0][getPriceID];`

Comment: What is `.append()` supposed to do? You're not appending anything.

Comment: Thank you Tibrogargan!  I had tried  var UpdateCostField = filterItemID[0][getPriceID]; but.. I added a period between filterItemID[0] and [getPriceID] like a dummy.  Thank you! That worked..